# Formula field displays blanks instead of desired result

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm stuck on a problem with a formula field in Crystal Reports and I keep going around in circles.  I'll try my best to explain it.

The report I'm creating will be exported as a data file.  It uses 3 tables, with `work_table` as the main table.  `work_table` is joined to a view called `order_item_with_aux` using two fields, `orderhdr_id` and `order_item_seq`; it's an inner join.  I don't think this has much bearing on my problem but, `work_table` is also joined to the `customer_address` table on `customer_id` and `customer_address_seq`.

In my output, I've included several fields from all three tables.  Where I'm stuck is creating a formula field to populate a `@Split` field.  Here's what I'm writing in my formula:

```
if {order_item_with_aux.zzaux_no_renewal_notices} = "Y" then "B"
else {work_table.split_value}
```

This results in the `@Split` field being populated with "B" for records on the `work_table` whose corresponding record on the `order_item_with_aux` view has `zzaux_no_renewal_notices` equal to "Y".  The value of `@Split` for all other records displayed is blank.  I've tried several variations of the above formula all to no avail.  I've also tried setting a variable and handling it that way, but again, no go.

Anyone have any ideas?  Please let me know if there's more info I can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test for null values first:

```
if isnull({order_item_with_aux.zzaux_no_renewal_notices}) then
  "missing value"
else if {order_item_with_aux.zzaux_no_renewal_notices} = "Y" then 
  "B"
else 
  {work_table.split_value}
```

Comment: oh good grief!  I thought about the null values earlier today, but I didn't put it as the first test.  I just tried your solution and it worked perfectly.  Thanks very much!